# Cordova WP8 - Push Notifications Callback

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, windows-phone-8

It appears there is no way to fire a "function" when the app is closed and navigated to via a "Toast" not while the app is open. I realize that you can do this:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            try
            {
                if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString["NavigatedFrom"] == "toast") // this is set on the server
                {
                    this.CordovaView.StartPageUri = new Uri("//www/index.html#notification-page", UriKind.Relative);




                }
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
            }
        }
```

The problem is that this triggers the app to be reloaded and all localstorage is lost. We can't use query strings as it fires an error when the app loads.

I'd like to try to do something like this in the callback:

```
 this.CordovaView.CordovaBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { // some script here to callback to the JS level });
```

But this appears the CordovaView isn't fully loaded at this point, and don't actually fire the function on the app side. Is there anything I can do to "force" this to wait on Cordova to be fully loaded before it fires this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an extra wrapper :

```
this.CordovaView.CordovaBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { 
"document.addEventListener('deviceready',function(){/*some script here to callback to the JS level*/ });"
});
```

== Update

The above does not work exactly as expected because in this case the event is firing before the CordovaBrowser page is even loaded.
JIRA issue here : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8776

Comment: This doesn't appear to work as well, due to the fact that it calls this error: http://im.grega.co/image/0s243W232J2b